# Toolbar showing an empty box

Tags: android, toolbar, android-support-library

I've never used the toolbar before, but starting with this new project I wanted to give it a try. However I'm already having troubles.
For all I know, I used appcompact toolbar to define the toolbar in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!--toolbar-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, in my activity I set it with getSupportActionBar()

```
protected void setupActionBar() {
    // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My custom toolbar!");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        logger.debug("Toolbar Setted");
    }
}
```

However result shows only an empty box with no title or functionality at all.
I don't understand what I'm missing out, the process should be pretty straight forward.
The style file I use is the following:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: make sure you have called setupActionBar()  method in onCreate. otherwise your code is perfect

Comment: it is called at the end of onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Create a toolbar.xml file in your layout folder and place this code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- Place what ever you want in your layout -->

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

add this toolbar in your activity layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <!-- Create your main layout here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity you can set your toolbar like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Still not working at all, it must be something else messing with this. My min api level is setted to 15, should that be a problem? Or should I manually put a title inside that frame?

Comment: no this is not the problem, i am using this code and its working for me what is the error you are getting

Comment: there's no console error, just the toolbar view is an empty box with no title in both runtime and visualizer.

Comment: o man this is working you have to place whatever you want to in the toolbar.xml file, you have to set the title maually

Comment: this is custom toolbar where you can place whatever you want to

Comment: really? but I don't understand, online example seems to show that no other hard code is necessary to set title or action buttons and everything is done with legacy action bar methods.

Comment: If that's the case, then it looks like toolbar is almost pointless if you don't intend to have high flexibility on his layout. How come this is now the standard.